# How to access variables and functions from within a class?

Tags: python, class, oop, email, global-variables

I am quite new to OOP, but I can see its benefits. I have written a class (structured on an example from zetcode) that makes a window and puts an entry box and a button in it. Also, I have a function that sends an email (my actual sending code comes from the module sendEmail that I made). The code:

```
import sendEmail
from tkinter import *

class mainWindow(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg = "#C2C2D6")

        self.parent = parent

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.parent.wm_title("Email")
        self.parent.config(height = 370, width = 670)

        email_entry = Entry(self, exportselection = 0, width = 200).pack()
        send_button = Button(self, text = "Send", command = self.send).pack()

        self.pack()

    def send(self):
        body = email_entry.get()
        sendEmail.sendEmail("jacob.kudria@gmail.com", "anon.vm45@gmail.com", "jacob.kudria", "2good4you!", body)

def main():
    root = Tk()
    main_window = mainWindow(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

First of all, this code doesn't work (the sending part), but that's not a surprise, I hope that the answer to this question will fix it. My main question is: how can I make the send function, and therefore the email_entry variable (the end function uses that variable) accessible from the outside? In other words, I want my graphics to be in a class, and the rest not. Basically, I declare the entry box variable in the class, but I want to use it *outside* of the class for the send function. Subsequently, I want to be able to access the send function from *inside* of the class for the send button. Does this involve making them global...?

Also, this code is probably by far not the best, I am still not very good with python. I will be improving it as I go along. Any tips on the code, besides my main question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `email_entry` a field of your class.

```
class mainWindow(Frame):
        # ...

    def initUI(self):
        # ...

        # note self here
        self.email_entry = Entry(self, exportselection = 0, width = 200).pack()
        # ...

    def send(self):
        # note self here
        body = self.email_entry.get()
        # ...
```

Basically, in your code `email_entry` is just a local variable of `initUI` function (method). You want it to be a field of your *instance*.

Comment: What do you mean by a "field"? And also, that still leaves the send function inside the class. It would be nice to have it outside, as to separate UI and actual actions... Or is that not a good idea..?

Comment: @JacobKudria `main_window` is an _instance_ of your class. The data “attached” to it is called _fields_. I guess, you'll find it useful to start with some basic article about OOP (almost eny will work). And you'll need to learn about basic things like _classes_, _objects_ (_instances_), _methods_, _fields_. Those are the most basic things in OOP, ans you'll have to understand them.

Comment: @JacobKudria Now to your second question. Think this way: your sending functiond will definitely need to access the text of `email_entry`. `email_entry_ is “contained” inside your window, so your function to access this data should also be a part of this window. Of course, there are different ways to implement this, but they are slightly more difficult. Start with the basics.

Comment: I see. I guess that the sending part is still kind of tied to the UI. I just wanted to have it so that what I see is wrapped in a class, and what it does is separate, maybe even wrapped inside its own class.

Comment: @JacobKudria You've got a class. You _instantiate_ it, and get an object. Objects have some data with them, and this data is conatined in fields. Maybe an example will help. If you've got a class `Notebook` when you instantiate it you get some concrete notebook, an object. When you right something in it, you actually associate some data with it. It means that the class `Notebook` has a field `data` and you can store there something.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense, especially the notebook example.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest would probably be to have `email_entry` be a field in your class. However, you could also return it from your `initUI` function:

```
def initUI(self):
    self.parent.wm_title("Email")
    self.parent.config(height = 370, width = 670)

    email_entry = Entry(self, exportselection = 0, width = 200).pack()
    send_button = Button(self, text = "Send", command = self.send).pack()

    self.pack()

    return email_entry
```

Comment: Where would that return to? If I return it, I could then simply use mainWindow.email_entry?

Comment: Oh, right. I didn't see that `__init__` is what calls `initUI`. In that case the only possibility I can see is to move the call to `initUI` out of the constructor, i.e. `main_window.initUI()` after constructing it.

Comment: I guess that's an option. Think of it though, it seems like an extra unneeded step...I'll try making it a field of the class.